# Проблемы с if-else

Tags: curl, php, mysql

Берется id, происходит парсинг, данные записываются, читаются, но если я опять ввожу тот же id, то опять происходит парсинг, а не вывод информации из SQL. Что не так? или я вообще далек от правильного решения?

```
<?php
    define ("HOST", "localhost");
    define ("DATABASE", "database");
    define ("MYSQL_USER", "user");
    define ("MYSQL_PASS", "pass");
    mysql_connect(HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS);
    mysql_query("set names utf8");
    mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
$id="25040";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM descript WHERE id='$id'");
if(description!=NULL){
$content = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ($content , CURLOPT_URL , "url?prodCode={$id}");
curl_setopt ($content , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);  
$product = curl_exec($content);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match('/\<h1 class=\"fn\">.*\<\/h1\>/Uis', $product, $title);
preg_match('/\<p class=\"description\">.*\<\/p\>/Uis', $product, $description);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `descript`(`id`,`title`,`description`) VALUES ('$id','$title[0]','$description[0]')");
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM descript WHERE id='$id'");
$res=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $res['title'];
echo $res['description'];
}
else{
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM descript WHERE id='$id'");
$res=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $res['title'];
echo $res['description'];
}
?>
```

Тоесть постоянно выполняется инструкция из "if", "else" даже ухом не шевелит.
Только не кидайтесь тапками, пожалуйста))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Инструкция IF выполняется потому, что условие

```
if(description!=NULL)
```

является не валидным.

Что необходимо изменить:

1. Получить результат запроса к MySQL в виде массива:

   `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM descript WHERE id='$id'");`

   `$res = mysql_fetch_array`($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC);`
2. Изменить условие для блока IF:

   `if (empty($res['description'])) {`
3. Оптимизировать код в блоке ELSE - удалить вызов методов `mysql_query` и `mysql_fetch_array`. Вызывать их нет необходимости, т.к. перед блоком IF происходит точно такая же выборка данных, и массив $res уже будет содержать всю необходимую информацию:

else {

```
echo $res['title'];
echo $res['description'];
```

}

После этих изменений блок IF будет срабатывать, если в таблице `descript` еще нет записи с `id` = $id

Если такая запись есть - будет работать блок ELSE

Comment: Спасибо огромное, спасли дико, сидел весь день думал как с этим справиться) Необходимость 3 пункта я подразумевал, но не стал делать)) еще раз ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(description!=NULL){
```

Имелось ввиду вероятно

```
 if(isset($description) && $description != null){
```

Comment: таким образом сразу выполняется инструкция "else" пропуская "if"

Comment: Если нужно запоминать положение - используйте сессию